# Python, threads starting in random order when using a thread lock

Tags: python, multithreading

really new to Python here and trying to get my head around threading. I have the code:

```
import threading, time

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        super(myThread, self).__init__()
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting ", self.name
        threadLock.acquire()
        print_time(self.name , self.counter, 3)
        #Free the lock to release the next thread
        print "%s released, ready for the next thread"%self.name
        threadLock.release()

class sillyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        threadLock.acquire()
        print "silly silly!"
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Silly silly!"
        threadLock.release()

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "%s: %s"%(threadName, time.ctime())
        counter -= 1


threadLock = threading.Lock() 
threads = []

# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)
thread3 = sillyThread()

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()


threads.append(thread1)
threads.append(thread2)
threads.append(thread3)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
    print "%s is finished"%t.name
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

I would expect Thread 1 to first start and Thread 2 and Thread 3 be put on block until Thread 1 finishes. So the order of execution would be Thread 1 , Thread 2 and Thread 3. However it varies and is different each time I run the code. For example sometimes Thread-3 will run first which doesn't make sense as I call the line `thread1.start()` first and it should be locked after. Could someone give me some pointers to why this might be happening please?

Comment: Wouldn't the order depend on which thread manages to grab the lock first (and then which thread grabs it second)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thread.start simply *schedules* a thread to start.  It doesn't actually start it then and there.  Rather, from that point on, the OS will take over and start the thread as it sees fit asynchronous to your main thread.

If you truly want to synchronize running of the threads, you'll need to do so yourself using a mutex or other synchronization primitive.