# Why is my threadpool hanging even after tasks have been completed?

Tags: python, threadpool

I have set up a thread pool executor with 4 threads. I have added 2 items to my queue to be processed. When I submit the tasks and retrieve futures, it appears the other 2 threads not processing items in the queue keep running and hang, even if they are not processing anything!

```
import time
import queue
import concurrent

def _read_queue(queue):
  msg = queue.get()
  time.sleep(2)
  queue.task_done()

n_threads = 4
q = queue.Queue()

q.put('test')
q.put("test2")

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_threads) as pool:
  futures = []
  for _ in range(n_threads):
    future = pool.submit(_read_queue, q)
    print(future.running())
    
  print("Why am running forever?")
```

How can I adjust my code so that threads that are not processing anything from the queue are shutdown so my program can terminate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `queue.get()` operation block your `ThreadPoolExecutor` threads.

```
for _ in range(n_threads):
    future = pool.submit(_read_queue, q)
    print(future.running())
```

Let's examine `future = pool.submit(_read_queue, q)` in every iteration of `for loop`

In first iteration of `for loop`, `pool.submit(_read_queue, q)` will put a job inside the  `ThreadPoolExecutor` `internal queue`. When any job are put inside the  `ThreadPoolExecutor` `internal queue` (it's name is `self._work_queue`), `submit` method will create a thread1(I say thread1,thread2.. for easily understand) thread. This thread will execute `_read_queue` `func`(This can be happen immediately  or this can be happen after the fourth iteration of for loop. This ordering is depends on the Operating System Scheduler, please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698172/python-threads-starting-in-random-order-when-using-a-thread-lock)) and `queue.get()` will return "test". Then, this thread will sleep for 2 seconds.

In second iteration of `for loop`, `pool.submit(_read_queue, q)` will put a job inside the  `ThreadPoolExecutor` internal queue and then `submit` method will check that there is any thread which is waiting for a job ? No, there is no any waiting thread, first thread is sleeping(for 2 seconds). So `submit` method will do below steps :

```
if "there is a thread which will accept a job immediately": #Step 1
    return
                                                            # Step 2
if numbe_of_created_threads(now this is 1) < self._max_workers:
    threading.Thread()....  #create a new thread
```

And then `submit` method will create a new  thread2 `thread` and this thread will execute `_read_queue` `func` and `queue.get()` will return "test2". Then, this thread will sleep for 2 seconds. Also, `q, queue` object will be empty and subsequent `get()` call will block the calling thread

In third iteration of `for loop`, `submit` method will put a job inside the `ThreadPoolExecutor` `internal queue` and then `submit` method will check that there is any thread which is waiting for a job ? There is no any waiting thread, first thread is sleeping(for 2 seconds) and second thread also is sleeping, so `submit` method will create a new  `thread3` thread (It will check the both **step1** and **Step2**) and this thread will execute `_read_queue` `func` same as other threads did. When `thread3` run, it will execute `queue.get()` but this will block the `thread3`, because `q,queue` object is empty and if you call [get(blocking=True)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.SimpleQueue.get) method of a empty queue object, your calling thread will be blocked .

In fourth iteration of `for loop`, this will be same as with third case, and then `thread4` will be blocked on `queue.get()` operation.

I assume 2 seconds not passed now, and there will be 5 thread which is alive (can be sleep mode or not) currently. After 2 seconds passed, `thread1` and `thread2`(because `time.sleep(2)` will return) will terminate***1** but `thread3` and `thread4` will not, because `queue.get()` blocking them. That's why your main thread (whole program) will wait them and not terminate.

What can we do in this situation ?

We can put two elements inside the `q` object because `q.get()` blocking your thread by using acquire a lock object. We can only release this lock by calling `release()` method, to do that we need to call `queue.put(something)`

Here is one of the solutions ;

```
import time,threading
import queue
from concurrent import futures

def _read_queue(queue):
    msg = queue.get()
    time.sleep(2)
    queue.put(None)

n_threads = 4
q = queue.Queue()

q.put('test')
q.put("test2")

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_threads) as pool:
    futures = []
    for _ in range(n_threads):
        futures.append(pool.submit(_read_queue, q))
```

*1, I said `ThreadPoolExecutor` threads will terminate after function finished,  but it is depend on calling the `shutdown()` method, If we don't call `shutdown(`) method of `pool` object, thread will not terminate even if function finished. Because creating and destruction a thread is costly, that's why threadpool concept is there.(`shutdown()` method will be called end of the `with` statement)

If I'm wrong somewhere please correct me.